# Slick2D setting width of image using Graphics.drawImage?

Tags: java, slick2d

Hello I am using the Slick2D game developing framework. In my game I need to change the width and height of some sprites, that I used to successfully do in the java graphics library.

I can't really figure out how to do this in Slick2D, does Slick2D offer this feature?
This is how i've done it in Graphics2D:

```
g.drawImage(this.s.getSprite(), this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, null);
```

How can I do this in Slick2D?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I need to get a new scaled copy with new width, height like this:

```
g.drawImage(this.s.getSprite().getScaledCopy(this.width, this.height), this.x, this.y);
```